# Javascript enumerable property in Python

Tags: python

I have classes that I want to represent in JSON

In Javascript, a getter property can be included or excluded of a Json.stringfy() if defined as enumerable: true/false like this:

```
class Example {

    constructor(){
        Object.defineProperties(this, {
            notEnumerableProperty: {
                get: function () {
                    return 'this is not enumerable';
                },
                enumerable: false
            },
            enumerableProperty: {
                get: function () {
                    return 'this is a enumerable';
                },
                enumerable: true
            }
        });
    }

}

const instance = new Example;

JSON.stringify(instance);
// output "{"enumerableProperty":"this is a enumerable"}"
```

In Python we can define a getter function as a property like in Javascript using @property  decorator.  But it doesn't list in a JSON:

```
#JSONEncoder as seen in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable
from json import JSONEncoder

class MyEncoder(JSONEncoder):
  def default(self, o):
      return o.__dict__    


#My class
class Example():

  def __init__(self):
    self.value = 'this value is enumerable'

  @property
  def enumerableProperty(self):
    return 'It cannot enumerable';

  @property
  def notEnumerableProperty(self):
    return 'It is not enumerable';

instance = Example()
toJson = MyEncoder().encode(instance)

print(toJson)
#output: {"value": "this value is enumerable"}
```

Is it possible to allow a property be enumerated into a JSON like in Javascript?

Comment: Can you share more of your python code, and what exactly you're trying to accomplish in python? Are you trying to represent python objects in JSON notation?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable for how you can customize the way a Python class is encoded in JSON.

Comment: Um, `json.dumps` does not support user-defined objects, and you have to extend the JSON encoder class with a custom encoder, where you could do whatever you want. So *what exactly are you doing*?

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this sort of thing is very "non-Pythonic", but you might be able to get some mileage out of creating a custom `property` decorator and then having a custom `JSONEncoder` that checks for this.  the decorator would be something like:

```
class property_nonenum(property):
    __slots__ = {'__doc__'}
```

which we could check for in an encoder by doing:

```
import json

class JsonObjectEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        ignore = set()
        cls = type(obj)
        for name in dir(cls):
            if name.startswith('_'):
                continue
            x = getattr(cls, name, None)
            if callable(x):
                # don't want methods
                ignore.add(name)
            elif isinstance(x, property):
                # ignore properties that aren't enumerable
                if isinstance(x, property_nonenum):
                    ignore.add(name)
        result = {}
        for name in dir(obj):
            if name.startswith('_') or name in ignore:
                continue
            result[name] = getattr(obj, name)
        return result
```

and we can test this with a dummy class:

```
class Example:
    __slots__ = {'foo'}

    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 10

    @property
    def bar(self):
        return 20

    @property_nonenum
    def baz(self):
        return 30

    def myfn(self):
        return 40

    myval = 50


print(json.dumps(Example(), cls=JsonObjectEncoder))
```

which gives me: `{"bar": 20, "foo": 10, "myval": 50}`

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom JSON encoder ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder)) and use `inspect.getmembers()` to get properties of class ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers)):

```
import inspect
import json

class my_class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__foo = 'Hello World!'
        self.i = 111

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self.__foo

class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        properties = [(name, getattr(o, name)) for name, value in inspect.getmembers(o.__class__, lambda p: isinstance(p, property))]
        values = [(name, value) for name, value in o.__dict__.items() if not name.startswith('_')]
        return dict(properties + values)

m = my_class()
print(json.dumps(m, cls=MyEncoder))
```

Prints:

```
{"foo": "Hello World!", "i": 111}
```